# Is there a way for Selenium to connect to an already open instance?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, automation, rpa, hcaptcha

I need to access a browser that is already open. I'm using Python, but if you have another language, I welcome help! I'm trying to access a website and when I break its captcha even manually (the browser is starting with Selenium) it simply reports that it's wrong even though it's right and I can't access the certificate. In anonymous mode it shows the certificate but when clicking it goes wrong anyway.

I tried to access in anonymous mode, as another user, doing different ways so the site wouldn't recognize the robot.

Comment: maybe you should first start browser with Selenium, and use standard  `input()` to stop script and wait for your press ENTER in console - so you will have time to resolve Captcha. And when you resolve Captcha then you can press ENTER and script will continue work.

Comment: some portals can recognize `Selenium` because it always use the same variables in JavaScript. And there is module [undetected-chromedriver](https://github.com/ultrafunkamsterdam/undetected-chromedriver)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can run chrome with command:

```
chrome.exe --remote-debugging-port=9222 --user-data-dir="D:/ChromeProfile"
```

the user-data-dir is a new dir for user data.

and in selenium, you should create driver like this:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium import webdriver
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress", "127.0.0.1:9222")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
```

remember use the same port.

Comment: The execution worked. Your information was accurate. But unfortunately, even doing it this way, I was unable to break the site's protection, it enters but even breaking the captcha it appears as if it were wrong, even doing it manually starting with Selenium it won't let me continue executing. Thanks for the help.